# Limit the type of a base class parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a code like this:

```
public static void ToUpperCase(params Control[] controls)
{
    foreach (Control oControl in controls)
    {
        if (oControl is TextBox)
        {
            oControl.TextChanged += (sndr, evnt) =>
            {
                TextBox txtControl = sndr as TextBox;
                int pos = txtControl.SelectionStart;
                txtControl.Text = txtControl.Text.ToUpper();
                txtControl.SelectionStart = pos;
            };
        }
        else if (oControl is ComboBox)
        {
            oControl.TextChanged += (sndr, evnt) =>
            {
                ComboBox cmbControl = sndr as ComboBox;
                int pos = cmbControl.SelectionStart;
                cmbControl.Text = cmbControl.Text.ToUpper();
                cmbControl.SelectionStart = pos;
            };
        }
        else throw new NotImplementedException(oControl.GetType().DeclaringType.ToString() + " is not allowed.");
    }
}
```

I want to limit the `params Control[] controls` to accept only a `TextBox` and a `ComboBox` type.

My code is in C#, framework 4, build in VS2010Pro, the project is in WinForms.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exclusively one or the other--as in, it will be an array of TextBoxes OR an array of ComboBoxes?  Or could it be an array of TextBoxes AND ComboBoxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you should use a common base class for TextBox or ComboBox but that is already Control. Also you cannot change the base classes of those.

The best I can come up with is to add a Debug.Assert to check the type.
Something like:

```
foreach (var control in controls)
    Debug.Assert((control is TextBox) || (control is ComboBox));
```

Comment: This is the most viable answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can't- they don't have a good common ancestor.

What you can (and probably should) do is make two overloads of your method, which take parameters of each:

```
public static void ToUpperCase(params TextBox[] controls)
{
    foreach (TextBox oControl in controls)
        oControl.TextChanged += (sndr, evnt) =>
        {
            TextBox txtControl = sndr as TextBox ;
            int pos = txtControl.SelectionStart;
            txtControl.Text = txtControl.Text.ToUpper();
            txtControl.SelectionStart = pos;
        };
}

public static void ToUpperCase(params ComboBox[] controls)
{
    foreach (ComboBoxControl oControl in controls)
        oControl.TextChanged += (sndr, evnt) =>
        {
            ComboBox txtControl = sndr as ComboBox;
            int pos = txtControl.SelectionStart;
            txtControl.Text = txtControl.Text.ToUpper();
            txtControl.SelectionStart = pos;
        };
}
```

Comment: This will not work if you want to pass TextBox and ComboBox objects simultaneously, so whether or not it is the correct answer depends on the original poster's answer to my first comment.

Comment: Of course not.  There is nothing for it, though- as I said they don't have a good common ancestor.  Their most specific base class is Control.  The other option is to validate at runtime, as Michael Keijzers suggests.

Comment: Yes, very true.  These are the two best answers of which I can think.

Comment: Compile time checking is always favourable above runtime checking; however in this case compile time checking seems not to be possible.

Comment: Are generics really required? Assuming TControl is supposed to be of base Control, having the parameter declared as a Control would achieve the same thing?, Control does not implement SelectionStart anyway so there is still going to need to be a condition in the AddTextChangedHandler to handle TextBoxes or ComboBoxes to get/set SelectionStart. I'm not sure its worth trying to have a common function to add this handler unless more common complexity was going to be added.

Comment: No, its a good point- they are not required, and in fact it cannot be generically implemented because of the points you mention.  I'll fix that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**OPTION ONE**

If you want to be able to pass the mixed collection of textboxes and comboboxed in your function and still have the static type check, what you can do is to implement it in a following way.

```
public interface ISupportUpperCase {
    event EventHandler ValueChanged;
    void TransformValueToUpperCase();
}

public class UpperCaseableTextbox : Textbox, ISupportUpperCase {
  //TextChanged event is already here, just use it.

  //Implement TransformValueToUpperCase in a way that suits your control
  public void TransformValueToUpperCase() {
     int pos = this.SelectionStart;
     this.Text = this.Text.ToUpper();
     this.SelectionStart = pos;
  }
}

public class UpperCaseableComboBox : ComboBox, ISupportUpperCase {
  //TextChanged event is already here, just use it.
  //Implement TransformValueToUpperCase in a way that suits your control
}
```

Then your function will be:

```
public static void ToUpperCase(params ISupportUpperCase[] controls)
{
    foreach (var oControl in controls)
    {
        oControl.TextChanged += (sndr, evnt) =>
        {
            oControl.TransformValueToUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this you end up with better encapsulation as only the specific control should know HOW to make ITS value UpperCase, not some magic functions somewhere around.
You will also be able to easily introduce more controls that support this feature without changing other functionality.

**OPTION TWO**

In fact, you may get rid of this function at all with the same approach, just slightly change the interface to:

```
public interface ISupportUpperCase {
    bool AlwaysInUpperCase { get; set }
}
```

so your controls will be fully responsible for this feature based on this flag:

```
public class UpperCaseableTextbox : Textbox, ISupportUpperCase {

  public bool AlwaysInUpperCase { get; set }

  //constructor
  public UpperCaseableTextbox () {
     this.TextChanged += (sender, args) => {
        if (this.AlwaysInUpperCase) {
           int pos = this.SelectionStart;
           this.Text = this.Text.ToUpper();
           this.SelectionStart = pos;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

So instead of having a function you can just set the property when you need the control to be always in upper case and the control will manage itself.